# PHP "array query" / multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table where I like to perform a query on. My table looks as following:

```
    date        activity    amount 
    --------    ------      -------- 
    day 1       drink       0 
    day 1       eat         1 
    day 1       breath      1 
    day 2       drink       0 
    day 2       eat         0 
    day 2       breath      0 
    day 3       drink       1 
    day 3       breath      0 
    day 4       eat         1 
    etc          
    etc          
    etc
```

What i'd like to do is to see when eat is 1, and for the days that is the fact, i'd like to display all activities for those days

```
//What I was doing right now is:

$activityarray = array();



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE activity='eat' AND amount='1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//this returns all rows where activity=eat and amount=1


do{
     //perform for each result row a new query; look for the 'date'=$row[date] from the first query and show all activities that have been done that day (activity=1)

     $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date='".$row[date]."'");
     $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);

     do{
         array_push($activityarray,$row2['activity']);
     }while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2));

}while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));


print_r($activityarray);
```

Since there are thousands of days and dozens of activities per day, this seems not to be the most efficient method to me. Is there a way I can do this more efficient with one query? (So: check all activities for the days that eat=1).
Hope anyone could me me out!

Comment: somethign like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE day =(select day from where activity='eat' AND amount='1')`

Comment: @Dagon That should be `WHERE day IN ...`

Comment: ahy, yup, it was just a quick though

Comment: Why bother storing the zeros (and, by extension, the ones)?

Comment: And mysql_? Aaaaaargh

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t2.activity = 'eat' AND t2.amount = 1
```

Comment: When I try that, I receive the following message:

The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET
 SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Comment: Try adding an index on the `date` column.

Comment: How do I do that? How does de query become to look like?

Comment: It doesn't change the query. You use the `CREATE INDEX` or `ALTER TABLE` command to add an index to the table. Read the manual for the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, especially if you have join size restrictions:

```
select *
from table as t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from table as t2
    where t2.date = t1.date
    and t2.activity = 'eat'
    and t2.amount = 1
    )
```